# twisted , return custom message to client after receiving request from client

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I have Written a simple code of http server and http client, i am able to successfully send messages to server in form of xml from client. here's my code.

client.py

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

from twisted.web.client import FileBodyProducer
from xml_dict import bm_xml

xml_str = bm_xml()
agent = Agent(reactor)
body = FileBodyProducer(StringIO(xml_str))

d = agent.request(
   'GET',
   'http://localhost:8080/',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Replication'],
            'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']}),
    body)

def cbResponse(response):
    print response.version
d.addCallback(cbResponse)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
   reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

server.py

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

def parse_xml(xml_str):
  print xml_str
  response = "xml_to_client"
  return response



class Simple(resource.Resource):
     isLeaf = True
     def render_GET(self, request):
        xml_request_str = request.content.read()
        response = parse_xml(xml_request_str)
        print response

 site = server.Site(Simple())
 reactor.listenTCP(8080, site) 
 reactor.run()
```

what i am trying to do here is from client i am sending an xml string to server, xml is generated from bm_xml module which is another file. this xml is successfully read to server, now once once server receives the xml, i need to parse this xml and return another xml string. i have the code to parse xml and construct another xml so that client receives this xml from server, but i do not know how to send the message to client from server. 
where all the changes would the required , in server or client ? i am assuming `cbresponse` is the one where changes has to be done in client , but i have no idea where the change should be done in server side. 
In server `response` variable is the one which i need to send to client.

Comment: arey you planning to make is a synchronous or asynchronous connection??

Comment: from the above requirement i think i am trying to make asynchronous connection. i am not sending large packets of data just plain xml structures. i dont think synchronous is neccessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code appears to already do what you are asking.  `Simple.render_GET` returns `response`.  `response` is what is sent to the client.  Perhaps you're unsure how to get the response after it has been sent to the client?  If so, the answer may be [readBody](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/client.py#L1748) ([more docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/web/howto/client.xhtml#L253)).

Comment: Yes , it's true, i an unable to get the response after it has been sent to client. I tried `print response`. it showed me the object location. it must be one line code right? I missing some thing here.

Comment: hey @Jean-Paul-Calderone, thanks for the link, but it's not making much of a progress for me, if it's not much of a trouble, can you post the answer, it will help me a lot, please.

Comment: Did you read the pages the links go to?  They give you the answer.  I'm not going to rewrite the documentation for you here.

Comment: Hey @Jean, sorry if my request annoyed you, I am new to twisted here. Any way , i have gone through the document and i understand there is nothing changes to be done in server.py except that `print response` has to be changed to `return response`. now i got what the changes had to be done in client.py . I will try my best to achieve it, if i do not get the results i might have to trouble you once again with my silly doubts. sorry Jean

Comment: Hey Jean , i have updated the answer , please check it out, Thanks for the Links.

Comment: Okay.  Glad you figured it out.  For what it's worth, you should probably edit your question in the future, rather than adding an answer that adds more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found what i wanted : this is my updated Code for client.py

```
 from StringIO import StringIO

 from twisted.internet import reactor
 from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
 from twisted.web.client import Agent
 from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
 from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

 from twisted.web.client import FileBodyProducer
 from xml_dict import bm_xml

 xml_str = bm_xml()
 agent = Agent(reactor)
 body = FileBodyProducer(StringIO(xml_str))

 class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
     def __init__(self, finished):
         self.finished = finished
         self.remaining = 1024 * 10

     def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            reply = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print reply

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
         print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
         self.finished.callback(None)


  d = agent.request(
   'POST',
   'http://localhost:8080/',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Replication'],
            'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']}),
    body)

  def cbRequest(response):
      finished = Deferred()
      response.deliverBody(BeginningPrinter(finished))
      return finished

  d.addCallback(cbRequest)

  def cbShutdown(ignored):
  reactor.stop()

  d.addBoth(cbShutdown)
  reactor.run()
```

and this is my server.py

```
  from twisted.web import server, resource
  from twisted.internet import reactor
  from xml_parser import parser
  from twisted.web.resource import Resource

  def parse_xml(xml_str):
       print xml_str
       xml_response = parser(xml_str)
       return xml_response

 class re_simple(Resource):
       isLeaf = True
       def render_POST(self, request):
            xml_request_str = request.content.read()
            xml_response = parse_xml(xml_request_str)
            return xml_response

 site = server.Site(re_simple())
 reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
 print "server started"
 reactor.run()
```

Now i send the Request : `<some Xml>` to  server 
and i get the response from server `<some response>` .

this is what i wanted.